# Fill Data At Oncreate at android Directly from the server

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services

I have master table in sqlServer on MainServer, and I need to fill data into spinner directly from the server on page load of android.

Can I do this?

Comment: is database lying at local or at web?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in the `onCreate`, this method runs in the GUI thread and should not be blocked with time-consuming operations. `onCreate` is only to populate the GUI when the activity is created.

Instead, fetch your data from DB first, then pass it to the Activity via Intent.

If this is the first thing you do in the application, then consider creating a load screen or showing a progress dialog while you are making the connection.

Notice that if the Activity is already created, `onCreate` may not be called the next time you return to it from other Activity.